# Можно ли ставить запятую между именем и фамилией человека

Tags: пунктуация

Если в разговорной речи, я говорю: гулял вчера с Алиной, Чиженок, было классно, где пауза перед фамилией, как будто уточнение с какой именно Алиной, можно ли так писать, будет ли ошибкой эта запятая или нет

Comment: Ставить можно, если уточнение, например, можно хоть через слово запятые ставить, но, звучать, будет, увы, странно. И перед было классно тире надо. : гулял вчера с Алиной, Чиженок - было классно! или : гулял вчера с Алиной (Чиженок) - было классно!

Answer (score 0):

Запятую ставить нельзя. Если нужно передать паузу в записи прямой речи, то примерно так:
"Вчера гулял с Алиной, э-э-э, Чиженок, было классно!"
Без прямой речи примрно так:
Вчера гулял с Алиной Чиженок, было классно! Правда фамилию не сразу вспомнил.
Или так
Вчера гулял с Алиной, которая Чиженок, было классно!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае слово ‟Чижёнок” будет являться пояснением (если вы произносите это с соответствующей пояснениям интонацией отступления) и будет обособляться запятыми. Говорящий доходит до слова Алина, понимает, что слушающий может не понимать, о какой именно Алине идёт речь, он делает отступление, произносит слово ‟Чижёнок”, а потом продолжает предложение.

Comment: Уточнением, если соблюдать терминологию.